# What is Lua number type length in bytes?

Tags: lua

What is the number format length in bytes?
This is a "multi type" data format. Is it 4 bytes? 8 bytes? How much? How can I get it programmatically? Does the length depend on the OS/processor type?

Here https://www.lua.org/pil/2.3.html the documentation says this is a double precision type. That is, it has 64 bits. Am I right?

Comment: Does it matter? What's the real problem you are having? Do you want to get it in Lua or in C?

Comment: I want to convert hex-string to numbers. I want to know maximum length of the string.

Comment: @Vyacheslav So actually to be pedantic you're after the integer precision in bits, no the size of the number type in bytes. :)

Comment: @Vyacheslav Then you should ask this as your question, or perhaps ask another question. It actually has a different answer.

Comment: It is safe to use 53-bit integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the version of Lua, and of course, how it's compiled.

5.3 has true integers, typically 64 bits. https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html

> The type number uses two internal representations, or two subtypes,
>   one called integer and the other called float.
>
> ...
>
> Standard Lua uses 64-bit integers and double-precision (64-bit)
>   floats, but you can also compile Lua so that it uses 32-bit integers
>   and/or single-precision (32-bit) floats.

Earlier versions always use 64-bit double-precision floating point, which effectively accurately represents up to 52-bit integers. Your link... https://www.lua.org/pil/2.3.html

Answer (score 6):

Like @Roddy said, it's slightly complicated with the integer type. Moreover, it depends on how your Lua is compiled.

Basically, in Lua 5.3, there are two types, the integer type `lua_Integer` and the number type `lua_Number`. You can get their lengths programatically from within Lua by [parsing a chunk header](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/ldump.c.html):

```
local chunk = string.dump(function() end)
print("lua_Integer", chunk:byte(16))
print("lua_Number", chunk:byte(17))
```

Typically both lengths will be 8 bytes. However on some embedded platforms you can find Luas where the lua_Number type is a float (4 bytes), a 32 bit integer or even weirder things.

Comment: Note that this only works in PUC-rio lua. It won't work in e.g. luajit

Comment: @daurnimator Yes, moreover the chunk header format depends on the version of Lua, so this only works for 5.3. If you need to support more Luas you need to check the version first and implement specific code for each of them.

Answer (score 3):

according to the Lua reference (for integers)

> In case of overflows in integer arithmetic, all operations wrap around, according to the usual rules of two-complement arithmetic. (In other words, they return the unique representable integer that is equal modulo 2^64 to the mathematical result.)

and for floating point

> With the exception of exponentiation and float division, the arithmetic operators work as follows: If both operands are integers, the operation is performed over integers and the result is an integer. Otherwise, if both operands are numbers or strings that can be converted to numbers (see §3.4.3), then they are converted to floats, the operation is performed following the usual rules for floating-point arithmetic (usually the IEEE 754 standard), and the result is a float.

Answer (score 0):

Lua as a language does not define what you ask for. The data type used for representing numbers may differ from version to version (note that the link to the free online version of "Programming in Lua" is about Lua 5.0), but primarily this is defined by the way Lua is compiled, as others already said.

Look at [`luaconf.h`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/luaconf.h.html) for all the details.

Regarding your actual problem (converting hex-string to numbers), you could look at the result of `tonumber()` on various input strings, compared to known results:

```
function hexConvertibeBytes()
    local i, s = 0, ''
    repeat
        i, s = i + 1, s .. 'FF'
        local n = tonumber( s, 16 )
    until n ~= 256^i - 1
    return i - 1
end
```

Comment: A simpler way to get the native integer width is `('%x'):format(0xffffffffffffffff)` - multiply by 4 to get the bit width, or divide by 2 to get the byte width. You can even extend the number of `ff`s if, for whatever reason, you want to check for Lua implementations with integers larger than 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `string.pack` as follows:

```
s = string.pack("J",0)
number_of_bytes = #s
```

Answer (score 0):

Lua supports specification of the byte length of floating point (4 == single precision, 8 == double precision) and length of integers (4 == 32bit, 8 == 64bit) at compile time.

To inspect/assert this at runtime you can use the following:

```lua
function float_bytes()
    return #string.pack("J", 0)
end

function int_bytes()
    return math.maxinteger == 2147483647 and 4 or math.maxinteger == 9223372036854775807 and 8 or nil
end
```

Comment: The question is 7.5 years old. Stackoverflow is great